# Doing something to all files in an entire tree

Tags: bash, unix

The scenario is that I want to convert all of my music files from .mp3 to .ogg. They are in a folder called "Music". In this folder there are folders and files. The files are .mp3s. The directories may contain .mp3s or directories which further contain .mp3s or directories, and so on. This is because some artists have albums which have parts and some do not, etc.

I want to write a script that converts each file using avconv.
Basically, what I am *going* to do is manually `cd` into every directory and run the following:

```
for file in $(ls); do avconv -i $file `echo \`basename $file .mp3\`.ogg`; done
```

This successfully gets me what I want. However, this is not great as I have a lot of folders, and manually going into each of them and executing this is slow.

My question, then, is how do I write a script that runs this in any directory that has .mp3s, and then goes into any subdirectory it finds and recursively calls itself? My intuition tells me to use Perl or Python because of the complex nature of this.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Do you *really* wish to use recursion? Isn't a simple `find . -name '*.mp3' -exec sh -c 'mp3="{}"; ogg="${mp3%.mp3}.ogg"; avconv -i "$mp3" "$ogg"' \;` enough?

Comment: Or `shopt -s globstar; for mp3_file in $rootdir/**/*.mp3; do whatever; done`.

Comment: @4ae1e1 likely I have to update my bash. 3.2.54(1)-release doesn't support `glob_star` (at least in the forementioned form).

Comment: @user3159253 It's new in 4.0. See [NEWS](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS).

Comment: @4ae1e1 This is working perfectly. Is it that the **/*.mp3 between just globs to all matching files in any directory? This is an amazing feature.

Comment: Quoting official docs: "If [the `globstar` option is] set, the pattern ‘**’ used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a ‘/’, only directories and subdirectories match." Just search for `**` in the docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `avconv` but assuming your command is:

```
avconv -i inputname outputname
```

And you want to convert all `inputname.mp3` to `inputname.ogg` in their original directories below `Music`, then the following should work in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r fname; do

    avconv -i "$fname" "${fname%.mp3}.ogg"

done < <(find /path/to/Music -type f -name "*.mp3")
```

**Note:** this does not remove the original `.mp3`, and the `space` between `< <` is required. Also note, `for file in $(ls)` is filled with potential for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with bash in one liner:

First you find all files (of type file (-type f) ) that match next pattern "*.mp3". To read each one you use 'while' and invoke avconf.
For exchange extension I prefer 'sed' command, that keep folder so you don't need the 'cd' command.
Notice that you must put quotes on $FN variable because it can contain spaces.

```
find -type f -iname "*.mp3" | while read "FN" ; do avconf -i "$FN" $(echo "$FN" | sed 's/\.mp3/\.ogg/g') ; done
```

Comment: Screwed if there's a file `music.mp3.mp3` (output file will be `music.ogg.ogg`). Use parameter expansion instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
find <music-folder> -type f -name '*.mp3' | \
    xargs -I{} bash -c 'mp3="$0"; ogg="${mp3%.mp3}.ogg"; avconv -i "$mp3" "$ogg";' {}
```

This should survive in cases of "weird" filenames with spaces, quotes and other strange symbols within.

Answer (score 0):

You can list directories with absolute paths and recursively cd into every directory using `find $PWD -type d` syntax:

Just inside from **Music** directory run:

```
for d in $(find $PWD -type d)
do
  cd $d
  for file in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)
  do
    echo $file
    avconv -i $file `echo \`basename $file .mp3\`.ogg`
  done
done
```